# how to display the parsed json using textfield on table view 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, json

hi i am new to iphone development

i am using a webservice to connect with where i am getting json response string and i am parsing json responsetring using JSONvalue and i am displaying the parsed json on the label using button...

when i click the button the parsed json it will display on label field..

my question is can v have a textfield,button and webview or tableview in the UI..

when i enter the particular method  in the textfield as json file is huge and press button shd display contents of particular method on the webview or tableview..

is this possible? if so then how to implement?

thank u

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


     [connection release];    

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    self.dataWebService = nil;

    NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*) [responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"]; 
    [responseString release];    


    NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];

    //fetch the data

    NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];

    NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];

    float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

    NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

    //set the text to the label
    label.numberOfLines = 0;

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ \n \n country:  %@ \n \n µamount $%.2f", name,country,outstandingAmount];
```

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @Nayefc Actually at present i have a button and a Label in UI when i press Button its display a result in LABEL..i.e, its fetching from JSON file and displaying on LABEL using parse json...Actually MY requirement is i shd have a Textfield,button and a webview in UI...when i enter a string in the TextField it shd search from the JSon file for  example "loans" in the above code..its contents shd display in webview... u got it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the loans in a table, you should read up on [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [Cell Styles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableViewCell)

you'll add your table, then indicate the number of sections, rows in each section, the content for each cell (row), and what to do if one of the rows is touched:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //after turning latestLoans into a property
    return self.latestLoans.count;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.latestLoans objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[self.latestLoans objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //do something with the row that was selected, like load a table of detailed information
}
```

Comment: what about a webview makes you want to use that as the display option? you could make a method that takes the JSON, loops through all of the results, converts it into HTML and displays that...is that along the lines of what you want?

Comment: woods yup u r rite u hv showed me how to do on tabelview thanks a lot..this has helped me.... but i wan code where we have a textfield button and webview in UI,where we enter a string in a textfield tat shd match with the string in the json file and shd display the matched method on webview...